# Значение вызовов в phpQuery

Tags: php

Имеются такие строки на странице:

```
$document = phpQuery::newDocument($html);
$items = $document->find('item');
```

Что здесь может значить "$document->find('item')"?

И еще:

```
$name = trim(pq($item)->find('title')->text());
$link = trim(pq($item)->find('link')->text());
```

Скорей всего в $name результат поиска по title. Но может кто точно объяснить, что это значит.

Comment: @Saturn, Это вопрос на передачу [Битва экстрасенсов](http://www.bitva-ekstrasensov.ru/).

---------------------------

А по существу, берете и смотрите код класса phpQuery, и находите ответы на свои вопросы...

Answer (score 1):

Не зная phpQuery, могу сказать что в name попадает значение тэга title. И ваши вопросы относятся к документации. Почитайте мануалы.